# How to inject custom validations in an AngularJS application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I'm trying to integrate AngularJS in my web application.
I've predefined validations that I've build over the time, so these custom validators I would like to integrate with AngularJS.

What I want to do is that make these validators in a separate javascript files and then only inject those validators which are required in an application.

Is it possible? And yes then how? I mean through which I would achieve this.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would isolate all the validations that doesn't interact with the DOM in a separate file / object so they don't depend on Angularjs (if you want to use it in other developments that doesn't use angularjs), then I would follow Yasin advice, create directives (they will interact with the DOM or ngModel or...) and will use your raw javascript validations.

To get started knowing how angularjs validations works you can follow this links:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation

http://www.benlesh.com/2012/12/angular-js-custom-validation-via.html

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write a directive for each kind of validation and add that to the input fields they apply to.

This link should get you started

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation

They have a validation for `integer` and `username`